# redistributing and using the CS.exe compiler (C#) for my application

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, redistributable

We are currently building an application which needs to compile C# code. Can we redistribute `csc.exe` in our package. I thought that it comes with the .Net framework installation but from looking in Microsoft Web site I see that there is a difference between .Net framework and the .Net SDK

What are my options?

Answer (score 16):

csc.exe is definitely part of the framework itself, not just the SDK.

However, you may not need to call out to csc.exe in the first place - there's [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) which lets you compile code programmatically.

Comment: Upvoting you is a sport now huh.

Answer (score 1):

csc.exe is available with the base installation of the framework.